# AngularJS calls HTTP multiple times in controller

Tags: json, http, angularjs

I am developing a page with Angular, and have an init() method in my controller. The code is as follows:

```
var filtersController = ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/json-tags-test',
            cache: true
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
   };
}];
```

It is just a call to a simple JSON file.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="container main-frame" ng-app="projectsApp" ng-controller="filtersController" ng-init="init()">
</div>
```

For some reason, this get call gets call twice every time I load the page. Is this standard behaviour?

Many thanks,

Dash

[image]

Comment: The answer at the bottom with the highest upvotes (currently 33) should be marked as the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This problem may also be caused by having an `ng-app` with routing to your controller and an `ng-controller` reference in your page. For example, if your app looks like:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>...</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myController">
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript defining the app:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]) {
$routeProvider.when('/path', {templateUrl: '...', controller: myController);
```

In the case above, with the defined routing to myController, the controller will be instantiated twice and you'll see two calls as described.

**Updated**

Above code describe what is problem but what is proper solution is missing so I updated answer as per @Intrepid comment.

Need to remove `ng-controller="myController"` from your html template if you already defined in route.

Comment: Good to know, it helped me to understand this better.

Comment: @user3195089 Thanks, but how to overcome this one? I mean what is the best practice.

Comment: I had the same issue myself where I had defined a controller in my HTML template AND also my route.  When I removed the ng-controller attribute from the template I no longer got methods being executed twice. Thanks for pointing this out as this one is quite easy to miss.

Comment: This is the real answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks. Saved my day.

Comment: This should be the marked correct answer for this question!

Comment: In my case, i define controller in routeProvider, and so in view, this is motive twice call the json. I delete in routeProvider. Thank for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is getting called twice, i just created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1dLqhv?p=preview) for you to see this.

```
var app = angular.module('projectsApp', []);
app.controller('filtersController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.status = 'Page loading';
  var count = 0;
    $scope.init = function () {
      $scope.status = 'API called';
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/json-tags-test',
            cache: true
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
            console.log('success');
            count++;
            $scope.status = 'successful: '+ count;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            console.log('error');
            count++;
            $scope.status = 'failed times: '+ count;
        });
   };
}]);
```

XHR logs from DEV tools

[image: Network console only one HTTP call]

**Edit:**

Updated plunk with a dummy json file

http://plnkr.co/edit/hTdtLK?p=preview

[image: Same seen in logs]

As you can see once again that its getting called only once. Clear the logs i guess you are seeing the logs for the previous page load, coz changes are immediately visible when in preview mode.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, I see that now; status outputs 1. However, Dev tools console is showing two "XHR finished loading" messages to the same URL? Is this a feature of dev tools?

Comment: in the console 1 get to see only one log for XHR finished loading for the url /json-tags-test. I will attached the screenshot as well. also please accept the answer if it helps you.  Thanks

Comment: OK, I see that, but it is attempting to load it twice in the Plunk too. Unless I am missing something. I have attached a screenshot to my OP so you can see, the difference being that it finds /jason-tags-test in the first call obviously.

Comment: @Dashman I checked it once again, its getting called only once and not twice. have attached the logs, screenshots and an updated plunk with a dummy file..

Comment: Wow, ok I have been completely overlooking the fact I had Angular concatenated in my lib-min file, and then another ref to it. This was causing it to run twice. Marking you answer as accepted as confirmed the code itself was OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UI-Router, better to use controllerAs in config and remove ng-controller in the view.

```js
 .state('master.userlist', {
               url: "userlist",
               views: {
                   userlist: {
                       templateUrl: 'app/user/userlist.html', 
                       controller: 'UserController',
                       controllerAs:'vm'
                   },
                   'detail@master.userlist': {
                       templateUrl: 'app/user/userdetail.html'
                   },
               }
           });
```